# Query with parameter returns different resultsets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query returning different resultsets each time it runs. Sometimes the second query returns data and sometimes it doesn't.

```
DECLARE @MinSentDateKey DATE = 
(
SELECT
    MIN([SentDateKey])
FROM 
    [dbo].[factEmail] [e]
WHERE 
    [DeliveredStatus] = 0
)

SELECT 
    [e].[EmailId],
    [e].[SentDateKey]
FROM 
    #Email e 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[factEmail] [o]
    WHERE
        [o].[MessageKey] = [e].[MessageKey]
    AND 
        [o].[EmailKey] = [e].[EmailKey]
    AND
        [o].[SentDateKey] >= @MinSentDateKey
)
```

I've isolated the issue to the following line

```
[o].[SentDateKey] >= @MinSentDateKey
```

as replacing the variable with the actual hard-coded value always returns the correct resultset. [o].[SentDateKey] is a DATE datetype and @MinSentDateKey never changes it's value. I've also noticed that this always returns the correct resultset:

```
 [o].[SentDateKey] >= DATEADD(DAY,0, @MinSentDateKey)
```

I have a feeling that this is caused by parameter sniffing and so far have tried  OPTION (RECOMPILE) with no luck.

EDIT: The data in  [dbo].[factEmail] and #Email is static and it does not change at any point.

Comment: I guess in some moments you do have `[DeliveredStatus] = 0` undelivered emails, sometimes not.

Comment: Parameter sniffing does not cause the results of a query to be different. As already stated the only thing that makes any sense here is that your data is changing.

Comment: As I have stated already, @MinSentDateKey always remains the same and the underlying data is not changing. Hard-coding the date value always returns the same number of rows. Using the variable returns either empty resultset or occasionally it returns the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate selects, why not combine them?

```
SELECT 
    [e].[EmailId],
    [e].[SentDateKey]
FROM 
    #Email e 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[factEmail] [o]
    WHERE
        [o].[MessageKey] = [e].[MessageKey]
    AND 
        [o].[EmailKey] = [e].[EmailKey]
    AND
        [o].[SentDateKey] >= 
        (
        SELECT
            MIN([SentDateKey])
        FROM 
            [dbo].[factEmail]
        WHERE 
            [DeliveredStatus] = 0
        )
)
```

This assumes that the MIN([SentDateKey]) it is selecting has the right value.

The other thing to do is not type @MinSentDateKey as a DATE but as a DateTime or maybe as a Date2 - whatever the table column actually is.

Comment: [o].[SentDateKey] is DATE and so is @MinSentDateKey. Using a subquery to replace the variable does work but I would like to know what is the problem in its current state.